# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=3,$ then prove $\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{4a+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{4b+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{4c+3}}\le 3\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

**Question.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$ Prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{4a+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{4b+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{4c+3}}\le 3\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}.$$
I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz and we need to prove
$$\frac{a+b}{4a+3}+\frac{b+c}{4b+3}+\frac{c+a}{4c+3}\le \frac{6}{7},$$which is wrong.

I found countered example $a=\dfrac{\sqrt{390}}{20};b=\dfrac{9}{20};c=\dfrac{27}{20}$ that $$\frac{a+b}{4a+3}+\frac{b+c}{4b+3}+\frac{c+a}{4c+3}-\frac{6}{7}\approx 0.00295.$$
Hope to see some better ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{4a+3}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{(4a+3)(4a+8b+3c)}\sum_{cyc}(4a+8b+3c)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{(4a+3)(4a+8b+3c)}\leq\frac{6}{35(a+b+c)},$$ which is true, but my proof of the last inequality is not so nice.

Comment: How did you get $4a+8b+3c$?

Comment: @Momo It's a Bacteria method.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg THank you. I upvoted your answer. It would be nice if you share how did you find that Holder using.

Comment: @Anonymous It's a similar to my using Bacteria here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814609