# Prove $\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}+\sqrt[3]{3b+ca}+\sqrt[3]{3c+ab}\le \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{a^2+b^2+c^2+29}$ for $ab+bc+ca=3.$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, uvw

If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3$ then prove $$\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}+\sqrt[3]{3b+ca}+\sqrt[3]{3c+ab}\le \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{a^2+b^2+c^2+29}.$$
I tried to use AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz without success.

Notice that $a^2+b^2+c^2+3\ge 2(a+b+c)$ but $$\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}+\sqrt[3]{3b+ca}+\sqrt[3]{3c+ab}\le \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{2(a+b+c)+26}$$ is not true when $a=b=\sqrt{3};c=0.$

I need some help to solve the problem. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

By Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}\right)^3\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{3a+bc}{(7a+5b+5c)^2}\left(\sum_{cyc}(7a+5b+5c)\right)^2$$ and it's enough to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{3a+bc}{(7a+5b+5c)^2}\leq\frac{27(a^2+b^2+c^2+29)}{2312(a+b+c)^2}$$ and $uvw$ kills it:

Easy to show that the last inequality it's $f(w^3)\geq0$, where $f$ is a concave function and it's enough to check two following cases.

1. $abc=0$;
2. $b=a$.

Can you end it now?

We can get the factor $(7a+5b+5c)^2$ by the following way.

For $k\geq0$ by Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}\right)^3\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{3a+bc}{(ka+b+c)^2}\left(\sum_{cyc}(ka+b+c)\right)^2$$ the equality occurs for
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}}{ka+b+c}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3b+ac}}{kb+a+c}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3c+ab}}{kc+a+b}.$$
For $c=0$ and $a=b=\sqrt3$ we have
$$\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{a^2+b^2+c^2+29}-\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{35}-2\sqrt3-\sqrt[3]3=0.000248...$$
Now,  from $(a,b,c)=\left(\sqrt3,\sqrt3,0\right)$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3a+bc}}{ka+b+c}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3c+ab}}{kc+a+b}$$ we obtain $$k=2\sqrt[6]3-1=1.4018...\approx\frac{7}{5},$$ which gives a legitimation to try to continue with $k=\frac{7}{5}$.

I tried and the inequality turned out true.

Comment: Your Holder using is nice enough! +1

Comment: Since $a=b=c=1$ is equality case, I don't know how did you find the yield $(7a+5b+5c)^2.$ Could you help me understand your Holder step?

Comment: It's Bacteria. In evening I'll show it. Just very busy now

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Bacteria is interesting.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for your help. Could you please make "Easy to show that the last inequality it's $f(w3)≥0$" more clearly?
,

Comment: @Dragon boy Someone wants to close your topic. Show please more attempts.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thanks for reminding me.